# Migrating MySQL database from local server to Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku

I have made a MySQL database on my local server.

I want to port this to Heroku. Would there be any way to do this without using ClearDB? ClearDB asks for account verification, credit card details etc. which I do not want to give. The rest of the application is hosted on Heroku, so I just need to migrate the database.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least three options:

- There are other Heroku addons that provide MySQL databases. I'm not sure if any of them let you get started without a credit card.
- You could use a MySQL provider that's not explicitly supported by Heroku and point your application to it manually.
- You could update your application to use PostgreSQL instead of MySQL and use Heroku's own Postgres service.